# Send Data Tables to MS Access DB using OleDB

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, oledb, jet

I have two data tables and need to store them into an Local Access Connection. I plan on running queries against both of them. (Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0). How do I store them into the local Access? Here is my thought process so far, i simply want them into the data set MyDB.Accdb.

```
 dt[0] is the first data table
dt[1] is the second data table
 // Global Variables 
        // 1) Create OleDB Connection
        OleDbConnection DBConnection = new OleDbConnection();
        // 2) Create a data Adapter(to get values from our Access Table)
        OleDbDataAdapter DataAdapter;
        // 3)a local data table to hold the values of Access Table
        DataTable LocalDataTable = new DataTable();
        // Variables used for navigated through table rows
        int rowPosition = 0;  // Index tracker used for "storing" data to DB at last(new) location
        int rowNumber = 0; // index tracker used for navigation when "reading" data from DB
        //1) set path of DB file
        DBConnection.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=MyDB.accdb";
        // Open Connection
        DBConnection.Open();
         OleDbCommand OledbInsertTable=new OleDbCommand("CREATE TABLE SPL_A (REFDES text, COMP_PART_NO text, COMP_SLH text, COMP_PART_NAME text, COMP_VALUE text, COMP_TOL text, COMP_RATED_POWER text, COMP_MAT text, COMP_PACKAGE text, SYM_MIRROR text, COMP_POPULATE text);",DBConnection);
        OleDbCommand OledbInsertTable1 = new OleDbCommand("CREATE TABLE SPL_B (REFDES text, COMP_PART_NO text, COMP_SLH text, COMP_PART_NAME text, COMP_VALUE text, COMP_TOL text, COMP_RATED_POWER text, COMP_MAT text, COMP_PACKAGE text, SYM_MIRROR text, COMP_POPULATE text);", DBConnection);
        OledbInsertTable.ExecuteNonQuery();
        OledbInsertTable1.ExecuteNonQuery();
         OleDbCommand OledbInsertData=new OleDbCommand("BULK INSERT SPL_A FROM '"+dt[0]+"' WITH (ROWTERMINATOR = '\n' )  " );
        OledbInsertData.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Is there a specfic function that saves time in sending the datatables since I already have data tables? Thanks,

Comment: You have two data tables where? Why not set a table link with Access External Data utility?

Comment: They aren't seen in the code. They are just dt[0] and dt[1], no use in seeing them. I just need a method of dealing with them.

Comment: How do I do that within the code? This project will be used by someone with no programming experience. The idea is for the person just to click run and it does it for them. I have to have it all programmed and done without the user having to do anything.

Comment: Sorry, not understanding. Where is this data coming from? dt[0] and dt[1] have to be built from something.

Comment: The data tables are  excel file converted to  data  tables. Basically just an excel file of data converted to a data table.

Comment: That's one way of doing it and is what I am using at the moment. I just figured someone had a better way of carrying it out.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to indicate what you have tried.

Comment: Converted to data tables - in what platform? SQLServer, Oracle, Access, MySQL, SQLExpress?

Comment: Access using what im using.

Comment: I edited my code to show my attempt.

Comment: `BULK INSERT` is T-SQL (SQL Server), not Access SQL.